# AngularJs - diretivas não funcionam via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, html5, angularjs-directives

Tenho uma pagina: `index.php` e a `app.js`. na minha `app` eu faço um `load` pra `main.php` que é o carregamento inicial do site. dentro da `main` ele trará `select`, `div` com `ng-repeat`, `ng-source`, etc.

Porém quando o conteúdo da main fazia parte da `index` funcionava normal, mais agora ele simplesmente não funciona mais carrega a pagina, mais as diretivas: `ng-repeat`, `ng-source`, etc parecem não funcionar. vou por um trecho do código para vocês verem

#### app.js

```
var app = angular.module("MeuApp", []);
app.controller("MeuAppCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
$scope.msg = "Olá Usuários";
var carregarMain = function() {
    $http.get("http://localhost/main.php").success(function(data, status) {

        $("#mainPage").html(data);
        carregarBanner();
    });
};
var carregarBanner = function() {
    $http.get("http://localhost/banner.php").success(function(data, status) 

{
            $scope.banners = data;
            alert(data[0].foto);
        });
    };
    carregarMain();
});
```

**index.php**

```
<div id="mainPage"></div>
```

**main.php**

```
<div ng-repeat="banner in banners">
  {{banner.foto}}
  <div class="item">
    <img ng-src="{{banner.foto}}" style="height: 600px;" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: coloca o arquivo completo da index pra vermos os imports

Comment: 1 - Coloque os códigos mais completos da index e da main.
2 - Por que você esta usando php sendo que você já esta usando angular e jquery? Uma que no seu código não tem nada de php sendo usado, outra que se você esta usando  angular, não tem a necessidade de usar nem jquery e muito menos php, quanto menos frameworks você carregar, melhor, tanto em questao de tamanho de uso de dados, quanto em questao de tempo de carregamento e ate integridade do seu codigo (ajuda a ter menos error bizarros por conflitos entre frameworks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eis aqui o que houve:

eu estava fazendo tudo, mais tudo errado! Eu estava chamando o arquivo main.php via http.get().

O que eu fiz:
1 - Transformei como indicado, os arquivos .php para .html, deixando somente os arquivos que me retornariam os json como .php
2 - ao inves de usar $http.get(), passei a utlizar ngRoute e ngView.
3 - Fiz as devidas correções no Controller mediante a tais alterações.

Pronto, ficou tudo belezinha, funcionando como queria. Valeu galera pelo esforço, vocês mais uma vez me ajudaram!